# wp_enqueue_scripts hangs

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

In the following snippet, when I add the `wp_enqueue_scripts call`, the page freezes.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function my_enqueue_stuff() {
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/homepage.css', array(), null, 'all');
  } else if ( is_page( 'corsi' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/corsi.css', array(), null, 'all');
  } else if ( is_page( 'dove-siamo' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dove-siamo.css', array(), null, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/map/gmap.js')
  } else if ( is_page( 'contatti' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/contatti.css', array(), null, 'all');
  } else if ( is_page( 'insegnanti' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/insegnanti.css', array(), null, 'all');
  } else if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'galleria') ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/galleria.css', array(), null, 'all');
  } else {
    /** do nothing */
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

Comment: The function is called `wp_enqueue_script`, not **scripts**. I'm talking about the _dove-siamo_ case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use is_page() in the function.php (citation needed!). Instead of enqueuing the the style sheets, you could echo them in the header.php.

So, in the header.php you'd want...

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/homepage.css">';
} else if ( is_page( 'corsi' ) ) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/corsi.css">';
```

Comment: Of course you can. In the `functions.php` file you define a function that is hooked into the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, that again is triggered on a frontend page. Meaning, when the function is executed, you sure can use `is_page`.

Comment: You know you're missing a semicolon after 'wp_enqueue_scripts('js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/map/gmap.js')**;**, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_front_page())
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/homepage.css', array(), null, 'all');
    elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'galleria'))
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/galleria.css', array(), null, 'all');
    else {
        $slug = get_post($GLOBALS['wp_query']->post->ID)->post_name;
        switch ($slug) {
            case 'corsi':
                wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/corsi.css', array(), null, 'all');
                break;
            case 'dove-siamo':
                wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/dove-siamo.css', array(), null, 'all');
                wp_enqueue_script('js', get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/map/gmap.js');
                break;
            case 'contatti':
                wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/contatti.css', array(), null, 'all');
                break;
            case 'insegnanti':
                wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/insegnanti.css', array(), null, 'all');
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```

**Notes**:

1. You could think about using the `$slug` inside your `wp_enqueue_style` if you have for each page a separate CSS file named `{$slug}.css`.
2. Why do you do this (using multiple stylesheets) anyway? Just use one instead and handle the different cases by using the body class `page-id-{ID}` or add your own body classes.